# Trapezium angle given, relation between sides

Tags: geometry

[image]

How do i check other options? Should i apply triangular inequality ? Also is there some way that all options are checked?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that (D) is true. Then, since you have established that (C) is true, we must have $BC=AC \implies \theta =60°$ which is clearly false.

If (A) was true, then $AD=CD\implies \angle ACD =60° \implies \angle ADC =60° \implies \angle PDC =120° \implies PCD =0°$ which again, is false.

If (B) was true, then $BC=CD \implies \angle BCD=\theta$.

Now, in $\triangle ABO$, ($O$ being the intersection of the diagonals of the quad.)

$\angle ABL = 60°-\theta \implies \angle AOB =120° \implies \angle AOD =60°\implies \angle ADO=60°\implies \angle PDC =120°-\theta \implies \angle PCD =\theta$

Now consider $\triangle BCD$. By the exterior angle property we have that $2\theta =\theta \implies \theta=0°$

False.